# Hp: unable to boot from DVD

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I have hp 2000 that comes preinstalled with windows 8, I'm trying to install windows 7 instead. Windows 7 is working, I tried it on hp pavillion.

I changed the boot order, I enabled legacy boot and changed boot order in that too. Still won't boot from dvd.

How to boot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes bios boot orders can behave strangely on laptops...

I normally tend to try and get up the boot menu to choose where I boot from rather than boot order.. Can you try the usual keys to bring this up on boot  F1, F2, F10,(Be Aware that some manufacturers use F10 for system recovery!) Esc, or Del?

Comment: In some cases it's F8.

Comment: i was able to access the boot menu by pressing f9 and they asked me what i want to boot